# vimrc set tabstop overridden by pathogen

Tags: vim

Here is my vimrc configuration:

```
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab

execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
colorscheme spacegray
```

The pathogen plugin overrides my setting of `tabstop`. When I disable pathogen, the tab and spaces in Vim works correctly. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't use pathogen I don't know if you can modify its behavior, but I would assume you can.  Check its documentation.

Alternatively, you can possibly override pathogen and other plugins--assuming they aren't setting options on autocmd events--by putting your settings in something like `~/.vim/after/plugin/overrides.vim`.

See:

```
:help 'runtimepath'
```

Specifically pay attention to this section of the help entry:

```
:help after-directory
```